# SVG font size relative to viewBox size

Tags: svg

Suppose I have the following simple SVN:

```
<svg viewBox="-3 -3 6 6 ">
   <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="0.2"/>
</svg>
```

Now I would like to add a text next to the circle, which has the same height as the circle, which is 0.2 in the chosen coordinate system.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the naive answer is to use the diameter of the circle as your size. That is, `font-size="0.4"`.

```html
<svg viewBox="-3 -3 6 6 ">
   <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="0.2"/>
   <text x="0.8" y="1.2" font-size="0.4" fill="red" font-family="Arial">XX</text>
</svg>
```

However, for nearly all fonts, that won't work.  That is because the font size refers to the em size, which measures from the highest coordinate of any glyph (often the top of an accent mark) to the lowest descender (for example the bottom of a 'g').

To match the height of the circle, you will need to user a higher font-size.  How much higher it needs to be depends on the font.  There is no automatic way to scale a font so a piece of text is always a set height.  You will just need to experiment and find the right value for the piece of text and the font that you are using.

Comment: Didn't know that fonts are measured in the same size unit as the other objects in SVG. So the answer is perfectly fine! :-)

Comment: I have, in a sense, the reverse problem: I want to create text that uses the page font size, but keeps that size independent of the viewBox. But I can't find any way to do this: if the viewBox width is 1000, and the page font size is 10px, the font is scaled to 10/1000 of the size, and is unreadable. Is there any way to work around this problem?

Comment: Anything insdie the SVG is affected by the viewBox <->viewport scaling (with the exception of stroke if `non-scaling-stroke` is enabled.  The only workaround you have would be to use JS to apply a dynamic transform="scale()"`` to your text elements.